# Python SMTPlib as Node.js child process fails at ehlo

Tags: python, node.js, smtp, child-process, smtplib

I've written a python script using smtplib which can send emails automatically etc. which works perfectly from cmd. However, when I try to spawn the script as a child process from the Node.js server I have running locally which I would like to integrate it in to, it fails at ehlo.

Do I need to change anything about my code so that the Node.js server can get in touch with the smtp server? Or do I scrap expediting this to Python and find a node package to help me accomplish this task?

Node.js (Express)

```
app.post('/emails', (request, response) => {
    console.log(request.body.orderNos.split(","));

    const orderNumbers = JSON.stringify(request.body.orderNos.split(", "));

    const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

    const python = spawn('py', ['./newemails.py', request.body.linkDate, orderNumbers]);

    python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('Pipe data from python script ...');
        dataToSend = data.toString();
        console.log(data.toString());
    });

    python.on('exit', (code) => {
        console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
    
        if (code == 0) {
            console.log(`Emails sent!`);
        } else { 
            console.log("Something went wrong with the Python script!");
            python.kill();
        }
    });

    python.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log("ERROR:" + data.toString());
        python.kill();
    });

    response.redirect("/");
});
```

Python

```
def send_email(receiver_email, first_name, week):
    message = """ #message content

"""

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = "#removed"
    msg['From'] = "#removed"
    msg['To'] = receiver_email
    msg.set_content(message)

    asparagus_cid = make_msgid()
    msg.add_alternative("""\
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        # email body
    </body>
    </html>
    """


    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port) as server:
        server.set_debuglevel(1)
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        server.send_message(msg)
        print("email sent")
```

The port is 465 as I'm using SSL and the smtp_server is definitely right as it's all working when I run python normally!

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

**EDIT: Not been fixed, but have been able to use Nodemailer successfully instead which skips the hassle of spawning a child process.**

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @nbk ERROR:send: 'ehlo [(ip address here)]\r\n'

Comment: The sender requires you to send `ehlo` and you are not doing that.

Comment: @tripleee it does it automatically when just running the python script alone...why is it not working when the exact same script is spawned from Node.js as a child process?

Comment: I really can't say; the SMTP protocol generally requires this, though some servers are more relaxed than others.